# 403 Forbidden Unity3D C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, web

I've been trying to get the information from this link: HIDDEN

Here is my current code

```
public static string newsLink = "HIDDEN";
public static readonly List<string> newsList = new List<string>();

void Start () {
    DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
    StartCoroutine (GetNews ());
}

IEnumerator GetNews(){
    WWW w = new WWW (newsLink);
    yield return w;
    if (w.error != null) {
        print (w.error);
    } else {
        List<string>temp = w.text.Split (']').ToList ();
        foreach(string a in temp)
        {
            newsList.Add (a);
        }
        w.Dispose ();
    }
  }
}
```

in the debugger I get the error message of 403 Forbidden

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The url you are making request to requires that you provide the User-Agent to identify who you are. You may need other headers to get the appropriate response but the User-Agent header is required to remove that `403` error thrown by the server.

Create the User-Agent (pretend to be Chrome)

```
string userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36";
Dictionary<string, string> ht = new Dictionary<string, string>();
ht["User-Agent"] = userAgent;
```

Then create the `WWW` request  with the header

```
WWW w = new WWW(newsLink, null, ht);
yield return w;
```

Note that you may end up receiving your Html and Javascript code instead of the message you get when you visit the link from a web browser. That's because your client(Unity) does not support Javascript and cannot execute your Javascript code.You have to re-write the server code with php. Finally, use json instead of `]` or `|` to seperate your messages.

Comment: Good answer, except I was a bit frightened by "You have to re-write the server code with php". Hopefully, there are other solutions than that, if you don't know php (node.js for instance).... But in essence, correct.

Comment: @Pac0 When I mean re-write server, I don't mean re-writing code like apache. I simply mean re-writing the code that responds to a url. Javascript shouldn't be used because most clients cannot execute it. So php or any other web programming language that can respond to a request should be fine.